# Storing excel-like data in a database in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm currently trying to make a vocabulary testing website in Ruby on Rails 4.0.0 and Ruby 2.0.0. I'm trying to create a system so that the user can create a list of words in two languages, and then compare them (the latter shouldn't be too hard, just a little bit of jQuery).

The ideal output would be that each table has two columns (`col1`, `col1ans`, `col2`, `col2ans`) and a `user_id` field. Another problem is that I'd like the user to choose the amount of columns and be able to add and delete them on the fly, so there would be no fixed amount but a limit such as 50. In an ideal system I could get some kind of hash into the db and read data from that, but I'm not sure rails will let me do that (I'm using SQLite in development and PostgreSQL in production).

As I mentioned, I am building this in rails so I won't be able to interface directly with the database. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I would love to give some help, but I don't understand what are you trying to do. Can you give an example so I can see what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually can save as hash in postgres by using an [hstore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/hstore.html).  Since you are using Rails 4, hstore is already a native datatype.

**Run a migration telling postgres to use hstore:**

```
class AddHstore < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute 'CREATE EXTENSION hstore'
  end

  def down
    execute 'DROP EXTENSION hstore'
  end
end
```

**Add hstore column just like any other**

```
class AddSettingsToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :users, :questions, :hstore
  end

  def down
    remove_column :users, :questions
  end
end
```

Code examples used from [here](http://mikecoutermarsh.com/2013/09/22/using-hstore-with-rails-4/).  You should check out the whole post.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, I recommend you make each question and answer a row, not a pair of columns. Adding and deleting rows on the fly is a common and ordinary database operation. Adding and deleting columns on the fly is not. Also, all rows in a table generally must have the same columns; one row cannot have more or less columns than another.

So consider a schema more like this:

```
id | user_id | question             | answer
==============================================
1  | 1       | Why is the sky blue? | Magic
2  | 1       | Why is grass green?  | Elves
3  | 2       | Are rocks edible?    | No
4  | 2       | How long is a day?   | 24 hours
```

With this schema it will be easy to add and delete questions, or select all questions for a given user.

Comment: I see what you mean. How would I order the rows in the way that the user created them, if I were to use this method?

Comment: Rails adds a `created_at` column to each table by default. [This guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering) can help you order the retrieved rows by `created_at`.

Comment: Yes, but surely the rows are created only when the data is sent (i.e when you click the submit button), and so the rows would all have exactly the same created at timestamp?